# Ora-22922 while inserting a blob in oracle table

Tags: .net, oracle

I am getting this error sporadically. The same transaction works fine if I retry. Below is my table definition.

```
lob(DOC_DATA) store as securefile LS_<mytablename>_DD1
(
tablespace DBLOB disable storage in row chunk 16k retention auto nocache logging
storage(maxextents unlimited pctincrease 0 freelists 12 freelist groups 2)
index LI_<mytablename>_DD1 (tablespace DBLOB storage(maxextents unlimited pctincrease 0 freelists 6))
)
```

I have a simple insert statement in my Stored procedure.

The algorithm is as below.

```
sp name (arrDocData IN mytablename%TYPE,)
begin
insert into table_name (col1,col2,blobcol) values (inval,inval2,arrDocData)
commit write batch nowait ;
exception
errmsg:=errormsg;
rollback
end SPname;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. I have already made sure that the `arrDocData` is not null.

Comment: [This posting asserts that](http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2009/03/ora-22922-nonexistent-lob-value.html) "ORA-22922 is a symptom of a program that is incorrectly handling LOB locators across transactions"  The rollback seems to be a potential issue.